# Connection to Redis cache failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-modules, ioredis

I have a node app connecting to a redis cache hosted on azure but whenever I'm trying to connect to it, the connection fails with an error message

I have enabled secure connection through a port and configured my node app accordingly

```
// This is my client module
const Redis = require("ioredis");

var client = new Redis(
    {
        port: 6380,
        tls: true,
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
        family:
        db: 0
    }
);
```

module.exports = client;

This is the error I encounter whenever I start my app:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1317:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:792:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:606:12)
```

The API ran for a while without any problems but then started throwing this error. My colleague is not having a problem running the same service and I'm assuming this is my machines certificates or lack of causing the issue. Any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the company wifi network I was using. The firewall did not allow me to connect to the cache.